Calling a child method from parent class - why is it "wrong"?
I get that the first methodology here is supposed to be bad, and the second one is suggested as better. But I'm not sure I really know why. The first way, the parent method is called, which then calls the child method to get more specifics. That seems less verbose than the second way, and I'm not sure I see anything wrong with it. But - you all tell me. And how wrong is wrong? Will I be ridiculed forever doing it that way?
(I first posted this in the discussion forum since it seemed like a philosophical question, but it got deleted and I was told to ask it as a question - so here I am)
class Parent_Class {
  function generate_results() {
     // ... do some things first that any child would need
     // ... then do more specific child things
     $this->generate_more_results();
  }
}

class Child_Class_A extends Parent_Class {
  function generate_more_results() {
    // ... do more things
  }
}

class Child_Class_B extends Parent_Class {
  function generate_more_results() {
    // ... do more things
  }
}


$a = new Child_Class_A();
$b = new Child_Class_B();
$a->generate_results();
$b->generate_results();

------

class Parent_Class {
  function generate_results_init() {
     // ... do initial things germane to all children
  }
}

class Child_Class_A extends Parent_Class {
  function generate_results() {
    $this->generate_results_init();
    // ... do more things
  }
}

class Child_Class_B extends Parent_Class {
  function generate_results() {
    $this->generate_results_init();
    // ... do more things
  }
}

$a = new Child_Class_A();
$b = new Child_Class_B();
$a->generate_results();
$b->generate_results();


I don't see anything wrong with method #1, but I would give the parent class an abstract function generate_more_results() so that the child classes are required to implement it. This way you cannot get in a situation where the parent class tries to call a non-existing method on the child class.

What happens when you create an instance of Parent_Class then call the generateResults method?

this is a perfect example to use an abstract class!

absolutely on the abstract class ... the above was short-handed pseudo code.


the first methodology here is supposed to be bad,

A parent class should never know anything about, or depend on, any children that might extend it. Dependencies should go in the other direction.

the second one is suggested as better

Yes, because the children are dependent on the parent, rather than the parent being dependent on the children. However, there's still a problem here, in that the parent is useless by itself. Instead, the parent should not be a concretion. I.e., rather than a parent and two children, make an abstract class and two concretions. In the abstract class, define an abstract method to require that children define it. And there's no need to explicitly call any init method because that functionality is already provided via constructors.
abstract class AbstractThing {
  function __construct() {
    // common setup here
  }
  abstract function generate_results();
}

class ThingA extends AbstractThing {
  function generate_results() {
    // do a thing
  }
}

class ThingB extends AbstractThing {
  function generate_results() {
    // do a different thing
  }
}

class ThingC extends AbstractThing {
  // compile-time error because no generate_results() method is defined.
}

[UPDATE]

That seems less verbose than the second way, and I'm not sure I see anything wrong with it. But - you all tell me. And how wrong is wrong? Will I be ridiculed forever doing it that way?

There is nothing "wrong" with either method, both will work. Of the two, the second is preferable according to modern best practices.
The first example is generally seen as undesirable because it does not support SOLID. It also requires the caller to know that they have to call two specific methods in a specific order. In testing, you now have to concern yourself with, "What happens if that doesn't happen?" In the second example, calling them out of order (or not at all) isn't even possible.
You won't be ridiculed, it's fantastic that you recognize there's a difference and that you're curious which is better and why.

I want some universal things done, then child things done. Every time. This is separate from the constructor's logic

I disagree. This is exactly what constructors are for. It sounds like you have larger, more complex classes that do other things in other methods that don't need this one-method-specific initialization. If this is the case then you're likely not adhering to the single responsibility principle or the interface segregation principle.
It also sounds like you feel these are the only two possible solutions here. If you're concerned about the subtle difference between example 1 and example 2, then you're probably going to want to keep going down that SOLID road, and you'd likely benefit from further extracting this logic. You might pull this result generation code into its own set of standalone pluggable classes using the strategy pattern, and then injecting a strategy instance into the bigger class at instantiation.

I know the latter things you mentioned - the above was just shorthand code. The point of the "init" above was that the method in the parent would do some things that were universal - and then the child methods would do additional things, all with just one method call. The calling script could do $obj->method_from_parent(); $obj->method_from_child() ... but that also seems overly verbose. Point being, every time I call that method, I want some universal things done, then child things done. Every time. This is separate from the constructor's logic, which does other things not pertinent here.

Again to clarify - this really wasn't a question of how to do any of the above. Moreso if the 1st example was "really that bad." I already know the rationale you suggested, and I get it, but I still don't see it as a problem, since example 2 seems more verbose.

[updated, see edit]
